# Zero function with integral inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I encountered seemingly trivial question but actually I stuck with the problem.

Show that if continuous function  $x(t)$ such that $t\in[0,\infty]$ satisfies inequality $0\leq x(t)\leq \alpha \int_0^t x(s) ds$ for positive $\alpha$.
Then $x(t) = 0$.

Comment: This follows from [Gronwall's inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) if you are familiar with that.

Comment: (The above found by some quick [approach0](https://approach0.xyz) searching. Also these AoPS threads [1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h541876), [2](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h541956p3123948).)